# How to sort table column by color?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to auto sort a table by color when user changes the cell color.

I want this for only one column, so I put it under `Worksheet_Change`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Set taskPriorityTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskPrioritiesTable")
  Set priorityRange = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TaskPrioritiesTable[PRIORITY]")
  
  If Target.Column = 3 Then
  
    If Not Intersect(Target, priorityRange) Is Nothing Then
        
      Dim ws As Worksheet

      Set ws = ActiveSheet
      
      MsgBox "sorting"

      With taskPriorityTable.Sort 'ws.Sort
        MsgBox "sorting by colors"

        With .SortFields
          .Clear
          .Add(Range("TaskPrioritiesTable[PRIORITY]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
          .Add(Range("TaskPrioritiesTable[PRIORITY]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, 235, 156)
          .Add(Range("TaskPrioritiesTable[PRIORITY]"), xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(198, 239, 206)

        End With
        MsgBox "sorting ended"
        .SetRange priorityRange.CurrentRegion
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply

      MsgBox "completed"
      End With

    End If
  MsgBox "text complete"

  End If
End Sub
```

It was working but it started to crash. I changed the `.Add(Range` from `.Add(priorityRange)` to the one in the code above. It still either crashes or doesn't sort.

I do see the msgbox popups now, but still doesn't sort. The RGB values are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort table ascending and descending using ListObject

The following code is going to sort the table from the lowest to the highest value.

```
Sub Sort()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("myTable")
    Set rng = Range("myTable[Numbers]")
    
    With tbl.Sort
       .SortFields.Clear
       .SortFields.Add Key:=rng, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending
       .Header = xlYes
       .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

**You can modify this snippet as you wish.**